# MySQL show 12 month interval without first partial month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I want to list the scores, by month, for something that happened over the last 12 months. I noticed my query below was combining the results of the first partial month with the results of the last partial month. That is, my July report combined July 9-31, 2015 with July 1-8 2016 (now is July 8). I only want the latest month to represent the latest year. Here is what I was using...

```
$query = "SELECT record_id, 
   time_scored, 
   MONTH(time_scored) as month_added, 
   score, comment 
FROM records 
WHERE score IS NOT NULL AND 
   time_scored >= DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH) 
ORDER BY time_scored DESC";
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what result you want exactly? I don't understand which "July" you want.

Comment: So I've got a function that calculates the raw scores into a new monthly score. 

Here's what I'm getting:
Jul    43 (this number includes both July 2015 and July 2016 data)
Jun    28
May    36
... etc...
Aug    23.

I suppose there's a way to move the July 2015 data in the function, but I'd rather just start without it in the original query.

Comment: So you want only data for July 2016? so from August 2015 to July 2016 (inclusive)?

Comment: Correct. The result would be a list showing those months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract 12 months from next months 1st day

```
$query = "SELECT record_id, 
   time_scored, 
   MONTH(time_scored) as month_added, 
   score, comment 
FROM records 
WHERE score IS NOT NULL AND 
   time_scored >= DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(subdate(curdate(), (day(curdate())-1)), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),INTERVAL 12 MONTH) 
ORDER BY time_scored DESC";
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much!